# Reposition an h1 tag,

Tags: html, css, position

Positioning the `<h1>` to the position that I want.

Here's what I am trying to do:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgzI0.jpg

CSS File and HTML File

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Montserrat:400,600');
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.header img {
  padding: 1em 2em;
  width: 10%;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 80px;
}

.header h1 {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="../Welcome/images/123.jpg" alt="">
    <h1> A Work In Progress</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

I tried everything that comes into my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if it helps :

[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0ghs6Lt9/1/)

```
.header img {
padding: 1em 2em;
width: 10%;
border-radius: 80px;
position: fixed;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Added `float: left;` and `position: fixed;`, also changed the `display` to `inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is use `position:fixed`:

```
.header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will keep it centered regardless of device coming into your site.

Play the with parameters a bit to get the exact position you want, also you might want to do this to the background aswell.

Comment: Thanks, it certainly helped!